# Show a lot of data in text Area flex

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have a little problem, I'm trying to input some data that I get with the library Capabilities.

I want to show version, language etc in a text area but I can only input just one capabilitie at the time.

This is what I have at the moment

```
<![CDATA[
        function displayResult()
        {
            var versionString = Capabilities.version;
            var versionString = Capabilities.language;
            var versionString = Capabilities.os;
            txtbox1.text = Capabilities.version;
            txtbox1.text = Capabilities.language;
            txtbox1.text = Capabilities.os;


        }

    ]]>
```

Since I want to show the result in the area box, I thought all I needed was to use the name txtbox1.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the three lines

```
txtbox1.text = Capabilities.version;
txtbox1.text = Capabilities.language;
txtbox1.text = Capabilities.os;
```

you change the value of `txtbox1.text` three times, so it only keeps the last value (`Capabilities.os`).

you should probably do something like this:

```
txtbox1.text = Capabilities.version + Capabilities.language + Capabilities.os;
```

Or with some more formatting:

```
txtbox1.text = "Version: " + Capabilities.version + "\n" +
             + "Language: " + Capabilities.language + "\n" +
             + "OS: " + Capabilities.os;
```

**Edit** If you want to change the language you can so it as follows:

```
var language : String = "";
if (Capabilities.language == "EN")
    language = "English"
else
    language = Capabilities.language

txtbox1.text = "Version: " + Capabilities.version + "\n" +
             + "Language: " + language+ "\n" +
             + "OS: " + Capabilities.os;
```

Comment: Maybe another tip :)
I have an if else statement that change language EN to English. It works but its doing the exact same thing as my first code. Just overwriting.

Thanks